# Flutter test navigation by timer in initState

Tags: flutter-test

does anyone know how to test this type of navigation? Is there a way to test this kind of "automatic" navigation?

```
Timer? _timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
        context,
        SplashPage.routeName,
      );
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
callNext(){

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2500), () {
    
    
      setState(() {
         Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
            context,
            SplashPage.routeName,
          );
      });
    
    });

}
```

---

in your init function call callNext();

```
init(){
callNext();
}
```